# An item with the same key has already been added. (Ajaxcontroltoolkit)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Can anyone help with this issue? I recieve this error in our logs every so often but the users say they didnt experience any issues.

Thanks

**Error Description**

> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.Inner
>   Exception-->An item with the same key has already been added. -
>   System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been
>   added. at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key,
>   TValue value, Boolean add) at
>   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerHelper.GetAssembly(String name)
>   at
>   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.IsScriptCombinable(ScriptEntry
>   scriptEntry, Boolean enableCdn) at
>   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.WriteScripts(List`1
>   scriptEntries, TextWriter outputWriter, Boolean enableCdn) at
>   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.GetCombinedRegisteredScriptContent(Boolean
>   enableCdn) at
>   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.LoadScriptReferences(HttpContextBase
>   context, String[] bundles, Boolean forCombineAndMinify) at
>   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

**Stack Trace:**

> - at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
> - at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean  includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> - at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean    includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> - at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
> - at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
> - at 
>     System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> - at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,    Boolean& completedSynchronously)Occured onSystem.Web - Boolean
>     HandleError(System.Exception) Inner Exception-->
> - at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue    value, Boolean add)
> - at AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerHelper.GetAssembly(String    name)
> - at    AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.IsScriptCombinable(ScriptEntry
>     scriptEntry, Boolean enableCdn)
> - at    AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.WriteScripts(List`1
>     scriptEntries, TextWriter outputWriter, Boolean enableCdn)
> - at    AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.GetCombinedRegisteredScriptContent(Boolean
>     enableCdn)
> - at    AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.LoadScriptReferences(HttpContextBase
>     context, String[] bundles, Boolean forCombineAndMinify)
> - at AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
> - at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
> - at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
> - at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
> - at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
> - at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean    includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Answer (score 0):

You are registering scripts with the same key (name). Check `ScriptManager` `<Scripts>` section, and all `RegisterClientScriptBlock` and `RegisterStartupScript` calls for duplicates.

Also use `IsClientScriptBlockRegistered` and `IsStartupScriptRegistered` before registering any scripts to avoid that in the future.